# Java Jackson Polymorphic - Match on interface field results in duplicate field name

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, polymorphism, deserialization

I was playing around with polymorphism in combination with Jackson. I have a working example but one thing is a bit weird for me. When generating the Json I get a duplicate field.

I have the following tree: Garden -> Animal -> Dog or Cat.

```
@Value
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true, access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Garden {
    public String location;
    public Animal animal;
}


@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, property = "name", visible = true, defaultImpl = Dog.class)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Dog.class, name = "Dog"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Cat.class, name = "Cat")}
)
public interface Animal {
}

@Value
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true, access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Cat implements Animal {
    public String name;
    public String nickname;
}

@Value
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true, access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Dog implements Animal {
    public String name;
    public String command;
}
```

The program:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Animal animal = new Dog("Dog", "Sit");
        Garden garden = new Garden("Utrecht", animal);

        try {
            String gardenJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(garden);

            System.out.println(gardenJson);

            Garden deserializedDog = objectMapper.readValue("{\"location\":\"Utrecht\",\"animal\":{\"name\":\"Dog\",\"command\":\"Sit\"}}", Garden.class);
            System.out.println("");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I deserialize from Json to Java, everything runs as expected (Using the following Json: {"location":"Utrecht","animal":{"name":"Dog","command":"Sit"}}). But when generating Json:

```
{"location":"Utrecht","animal":{"name":"Dog","name":"Dog","command":"Sit"}}
```

How to get rid of the duplicate name property?

Answer (score 1):

Replace EXTERNAL_PROPERTY with EXISTING_PROPERTY.
So your example line:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, property = "name", visible = true, defaultImpl = Dog.class)
```

needs to be replaced by:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "name", visible = true, defaultImpl = Dog.class)
```

Comment: It works like a charm ! Thanks a lot :)